# Using abs () method in java. My compiler doesn't know the method

Tags: java

I have a simple question, but i can't find a solution for it.

I want to use `abs()` method, but it doesn't work. I'm always getting the error

> Cannot find symbol: method abs(int)

I have already tried to use the method by including `"import java.math"` above the code. But that doens't work too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you using:

```
Math.abs()
```

or just

```
abs()
```

?

> Use **`Math.abs()`**

Answer (score 16):

Call it as

`Math.abs(number)`

or import as:

`import static java.lang.Math.abs;`

Answer (score 8):

All functions in Java are part of a class.  abs() is a static member of the Math class, so call

```
 Math.abs(val);
```

It's in java.lang, so no need to import anything

Answer (score 6):

It's a static method. It has to be used like this:

```
Math.abs(int);
```

[javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29)

[See Class Methods in the Java Tutorial.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Or you can use a static import: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: @Apache Fan - True. But I think it is usually better to keep Math in so it is clear to the reader where the method comes from. If you are just using abs and using it a lot the yes, `import static javs.lang.Math.abs;`  is a good idea.

Comment: I completely agree with you that static import of Math can lead to a lot of hard to understand code.

Answer (score 4):

You have to refer to the `Math` class when you use it:

```
Math.abs(<intval>)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's `java.lang.Math` (your package was wrong and Math is capitalized) but that's not a problem since all classes in `java.lang` are automatically imported.

As Brian says, use `Math.abs()`.  Or, you can import the methods statically:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

This will allow you to use just `abs()` (and all other static methods from the `Math` class) without prefixing them with `Math.`